# html javascript set max of input field according to option

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<select required class="bg-mega" id="size" name="size" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; border: 0px;">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="S" title="25 available!">Small</option>
          <option value="N" title="15 available!">Normal</option>
          <option value="L" title="10 available!">Large</option>
          <option value="XL" title="20 available!">extra Large</option>          
      </select>
      
      <input type="number" name="price-quanti" id="price"  placeholder="Select Quantity" style="height: 30px; width: 100px;" max="should change according to size"  min="1" required>
```

I need small help in here.The scenario here is that when any value is selected, the max should be according to it. Like if i select large, the input field should have max of 10. Also if i select normal, the max of input field should should be 15.

Comment: did you attempt to solve this problem? You should try it first and when you have a question about your attempt you can post that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand SO is not a free coding service. You have to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I am really sorry. i don't know Javascript. i am new in php as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
updateTextfield = function(obj){
  $('#price').attr('max-value', $($(obj).find('option:selected')[0]).attr('av'))
  CheckMaxValue(document.getElementById('price'))
 }
 
 CheckMaxValue = function(obj){
  if(parseInt(obj.value) > parseInt(obj.getAttribute('max-value'))){
    obj.value = obj.getAttribute('max-value')
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required class="bg-mega" id="size" name="size" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; border: 0px;" onchange="updateTextfield(this)">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="S" title="25 available!" av="25">Small</option>
          <option value="N" title="15 available!" av="15">Normal</option>
          <option value="L" title="10 available!" av="10">Large</option>
          <option value="XL" title="20 available!" av="20">extra Large</option>          
      </select>
      
      <input type="number" name="price-quanti" id="price"  placeholder="Select Quantity" style="height: 30px; width: 100px;" max="should change according to size"  min="1" required onkeyup="CheckMaxValue(this)">
```

Any question don't hesitate on asking

Answer (score 0):

Check with Javascript which option is selected then change the max by editing the attribute using DOM.

To see if it is selected :

```
document.getElementsByTagName[elementToCheck]("option").selected
```

To se the max size of the input :

```
document.getElementById("price").setAttribute("max", value);
```